# When presenting a custom modal view, how do I "fade out" the colors of the controls in the background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiview, ios8

This seems like a really simple question, butI cannot find the answer to it.

In iOS 7, when presenting a modal view controller that doesn't take up all of the screen, such as a `UIAlertController`, it fades out the colors in the background from, say, blue, to grey to indicate they can't be interacted with.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `tintAdjustmentMode` of some view high up in the hierarchy. The dimming will propagate down.